# HTML - DIV not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8
I have this piece of code in my JSP

```
  <div class="col-md-12" id="secondSignatoryDivId" >                                                    
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>First name</b></th>
                <th><b>Last name</b></th>
                <th><b>Position</b></th>
                <th><b>Title</b></th>
                <th><b>Actions</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.firstname}" <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.lastname}"  <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.position}"  <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.title}"     <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> class="form-control"/></td>                                                               
                <td>Delete</td>                                                     
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<c:if test="${empty applicationForm.application.secondSignatory}">
    <script>
    alert ('lalalal');
    $('#secondSignatoryDivId').hide();
    </script>
</c:if>
```

I see the alert but the div does not hide !

Comment: Are you getting error in browser console? Nothing obvious wrong with code

Comment: `alert($('#secondSignatoryDivId').length)` Run it and see it gives 1 or not.

Comment: Seems `$ is undefined`?

Comment: Also Check, you have included jQuery.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#secondSignatoryDivId').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Include Jquery  in your html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery, you should include jQuery on your html file:

```js
alert('lalalal');
$('#secondSignatoryDivId').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="secondSignatoryDivId">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><b>First name</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Last name</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Position</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Title</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Actions</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.firstname}" <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>class="form-control"/></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.lastname}" <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>class="form-control"/></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.position}" <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>class="form-control"/></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory.title}" <c:if test="${readonly}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>class="form-control"/></td>
        <td>Delete</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for hiding the element then better to do it with ***css***:

```
<c:if test="${empty applicationForm.application.secondSignatory}">
    <style>
       #secondSignatoryDivId.col-md-12 { display:none; }
    </style>
</c:if>
```